# Splitting digits into groups of threes, from right to left using regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I have a string  '1234567890' that I want split into groups of threes, starting from right to left, with the left most group ranging from one digit to 3-digits (depending on how many digits are left over)

Essentially, it's the same procedure as adding commas to a long number, except, I also want to extract the last three digits as well.

I tried using look-arounds but couldn't figure out a way to get the last three
digits.

```
string = '1234567890'
re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})+$)')
re.findall(pattern, string)

['1', '234', '567']
```

Expected output is (I don't need commas):

```
 ['1', '234', '567', 789]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appreciate that if we add commas from right to left, for each group of three complete digits, then we can simply do a regex replace all of three digits with those three digits followed by a comma.  In the code snippet below, I reverse the numbers string, do the comma work, then reverse again to arrive at the output we want.

```
string = '1234567890'
string = re.sub(r'(?=\d{4})(\d{3})', r'\1,', string[::-1])[::-1]
print string.split(',')
string = '123456789'
string = re.sub(r'(?=\d{4})(\d{3})', r'\1,', string[::-1])[::-1]
print string.split(',')
```

**Output:**

```
['1', '234', '567', '890']
['123', '456', '789']
```

One part of the regex used for replacement might warrant further explanation.  I added a positive lookahead `(?=\d{4})` to the start of the pattern.  This is there to ensure that we *don't* add a comma after a final group of three digits, should that occur.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for this, but is there a way to get the output in a form like this:  `['1', '234', '567', 789]` . I don't need the entire string returned with commas in between. I want the output to be groups of threes. Sorry for the confusion. I updated the OP.

Comment: @Moondra Sure, you could just slightly modify my original answer and use `string.split(',')` to get an array of values which were comma separated in the number.

Comment: @Thank you! I forgot about split.

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is actually easier to operate on a reversed string to keep track of groups of 3 digits where there are more digits to go (with the positive lookahead of `(?=\d)`:

```
for s in ('123','1234','123456789','1234567890'):
    print(re.sub(r'(\d\d\d)(?=\d)',r'\1,',s[::-1])[::-1])
```

Or a negative lookahead version:

```
for s in ('123','1234','123456789','1234567890'):
    print(re.sub(r'(\d\d\d)(?!$)',r'\1,',s[::-1])[::-1])
```

Either prints:

```
123
1,234
123,456,789
1,234,567,890
```

Applying a reversed regex on a reversed string is called a [sexeger](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node=sexeger) in Perl ;-)

You can also do a lookahead version that does not require reversing the string:

```
for s in ('123','1234','123456789','1234567890'):
   print(re.sub(r'(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)',r'\1,',s))
# same output
```

---

Based on the comment, just add an appropriate delimiter and then `.split` on that:

```
>>> for s in ('123','1234','123456789','1234567890'):
...     re.sub(r'(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)',r'\1\t',s).split('\t')
... 
['123']
['1', '234']
['123', '456', '789']
['1', '234', '567', '890']
```

Or, skip the regex and just do it in Python:

```
for s in ('123','1234','123456789','1234567890'):
    s=s[::-1]
    n=3
    print([s[i:i+n][::-1] for i in range(0,len(s),n)][::-1])
# same output
```

Comment: Apologies for calling you out earlier +1 ... I think your regex option which doesn't involve reversing (and then un-reversing) the string is by far the best answer given, certainly in terms of performance.

Comment: @dawg Thanks for this. But is there a way to get the output in a form like this:  `['1', '234', '567', 789]` . I don't need the entire string returned with commas in between. I want the output to be groups of threes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks. It actually may *not* be the best in performance. Read the [sexeger](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node=sexeger) (in Perl) for a comparison. Bottom line, it depends on the regex engine and the speed of string reversal.

Answer (score 2):

You were very close. The problem is that the `+` in the lookahead subexpression will make the whole expression fail when you're in the last group, because there will be no group of 1 to 3 digits that is followed by at least one group of 3 digits (which is what the lookahead subexpression specifies).

Think of what happens when you try with `123`. Your expression will only match if there is a group of 1 to 3 digits followed by *at least one* group of 3 digits. That doesn't happen in this case, because the group of 3 digits `123` is not followed by anything, therefore the expression will fail, and that group won't be included in the output.

Just changing the `+` to a `*` suffices to fix the issue, as there doesn't need to be any group of 3 digits after the current group of 1 to 3 digits in order to match:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})*$)')
>>> pattern.findall('1')
['1']
>>> pattern.findall('123')
['123']
>>> pattern.findall('1234')
['1', '234']
>>> pattern.findall('123456789')
['123', '456', '789']
>>> pattern.findall('1234567890')
['1', '234', '567', '890']
>>> pattern.findall('')
[]
```